# Why does my water heater heat past the set temperature?

Tags: water-heater

Rheem Marathon 85 gl electric water heater set at 120 degrees started putting out scalding water.

Thought it was the thermostats so replaced both. Didn't have any effect!

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's the water heater and not a faulty faucet somewhere? Have you checked the output temperature?

Comment: The thermostat might not be immersed, so is reading the wrong temp. It could also be that the thermostat controls a relay, and the relay could be stuck closed.

Comment: Turn off the heater so you don't have damage.

Comment: On all of the water heater thermostats I have replaced this is the complete unit, the element is connected no external parts other than that so this sounds unusual to me, could you provide photos of the parts you replaced.